# Unable to populate dropdown in angular reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I was able to populate dropdowns when using template driven forms but now in material reactive form i am unable to do so. I am trying to populate `country` dropdown so that i might be able to call a `onstatechange` event later on to populate `states` according to the selected country. Here is my code

```
    <div fxLayout="row wrap" class="pt-4">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="33">
            <mat-label>Select a Country</mat-label>
            <mat-select [compareWith]="compareThese" formControlName="countryCtrl" (selectionChange)="loadState($event)">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let item of countriesData$ | async" [value]="item.id">
                    {{ item.name }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-icon matSuffix class="disabled-text">account_circle</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="34" class="px-8">
            <mat-label>Select a State</mat-label>
            <mat-select [compareWith]="compareThese" formControlName="stateCtrl" (selectionChange)="loadCity($event)">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredStates$ | async" [value]="item.id">
                    {{ item.name }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-icon matSuffix class="disabled-text">account_circle</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="33">
            <mat-label>Select a City</mat-label>
            <mat-select [compareWith]="compareThese" formControlName="cityCtrl">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let ele of filteredCities$ | async" [value]="ele.id">
                    {{ ele.name }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-icon matSuffix class="disabled-text">account_circle</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

Here is how my JSON looks

[image]

ts file code

```
export class ManualFormComponent implements OnInit {

  countryCtrl: any;
  stateCtrl: any = {};
  cityCtrl: any = {};
  manualOrderForm: FormGroup;
  zoom: any;

  countriesData$: Observable<ICountry[]>;
  filteredStates$: Observable<IState[]>;
  filteredCities$: Observable<ICity[]>;

  constructor(
    private _cityStateService: CountryStateCityService,
    private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.manualOrderForm = this._fb.group({
      countryCtrl: [[], Validators.required], 
      stateCtrl: [[], Validators.required],
      cityCtrl: [[], Validators.required],
    });
  }

  submit() {
    console.log(this.manualOrderForm);
  }

  compareThese(o1: any, o2: any) {
    return o1 === o2 ? true : false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._cityStateService.getCountriesStatesCity().subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val);
      this.countriesData$ = val[0];
      console.log(this.countriesData$);
    });
  }

}
```

Interface for Country

```
import { IState } from './iState';

export interface ICountry {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  states: IState[];
}
```

State

```
import { ICity } from './iCity';
export interface IState {
  cities: ICity[];
  id: string;
  name: string;
  countryId: string;
}
```

Comment: I could be blind, but have you tried this.countriesData$ = val[0].states?

Comment: Can you update your post to include your ICountry ts please? Have you tried: countriesData$: any; instead of countriesData$: Observable<ICountry[]>;?

Comment: Perfect. Try stripping | async off  of countries select and see what you get.

Comment: @Plochie can you copy paste this code inside your service and then populate the dropdown with only country names? `export class DataService {

  constructor() { }

  getData(): Observable<{name: string, id: string}[]> {
    return of([
      { id: '5da06f27b2dcbf00125c908a', name: 'Pakitan', states: [
        { name: 'Value 1', id: 'val1' },
        { name: 'Value 2', id: 'val2' },
        { name: 'Value 3', id: 'val3' },
        { name: 'Value 4', id: 'val4' },
        { name: 'Value 5', id: 'val5' }
      ] }
    ]);
  }

}`

Comment: Its working fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjppcq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `mat-select` in Reactive form, you need to have `FormControl` for storing value from `form` and separate class variable for storing the options array of values.

**Component**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  form: FormGroup;

  dropdownval = [ ]; // variable to store array (options)

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      dropdown: ['', Validators.required] // form control which will hold form selected value
    });
  }

  onEvent() {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.dropdownval = res;
    })
  }
}
```

**Template**

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Select a Country</mat-label>
    <!-- dropdown is used for formcontrol value -->
        <mat-select [formControl]="dropdown">
      <!-- dropdownval holds values for options -->
            <mat-option *ngFor="let item of dropdownval"> 
                {{ item.name }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

I have prepered the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqzgek). I have considered the case where you are getting data from service. So click on get data first, then you'll see the dropdown populated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was just making it difficult for myself by using `res[0]` to specifically target the first object. Its working fine now thanks.